# Folder in _Layouts/ not see

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation, visual-studio-2015

I create the project "*SharePoint 2013 - empty Project*", add *SharePoint Layouts Mapped Folder*, then add to script file, path `/_Layouts/SearchWords/jquery.min.js`and publish project. I see my folder in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` but not see in `http://sp/_Layouts/` after publish project. **"SharePoint Server Publishing"** is activate to all sites and subsite. What is the problem, how is the fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using absolute path to the file like given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/SearchWords/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or for short path, try using below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/SearchWords/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, i understand to my need "_layouts/15"

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSLink with `~sitecollection` token to get current site collection dynamically

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="jqueryScript" language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/_layouts/15/SearchWords/jquery.min.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server"/>
```

Or `~layouts` token to get URL of the Layouts virtual folder for the current website

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" name="~layouts/SearchWords/jquery.min.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server"/>
```